# JavaScript / jQuery don't work in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I don't want to provide a source code because the same  code works perfectly on a different PC or on a different eclipse version. The project is a Java EE project with servlets and JSP-s, and I want to use some js functions in a JSP file. How can I set my eclipse to understand and execute jQuery and JavaScript functions? BTW I have installed JSDT jQuery on my eclipse but still doesn't work. Thank you.

Comment: *"How can I set my eclipse to understand and execute jQuery and JavaScript functions?"* - You want Eclipse to *execute* JS? As compared to the browser executing it? Is the problem that your code doesn't work in the browser, or that you want to have autocomplete/syntax checking at design time in Eclipse, or...?

Answer (score 0):

Have you searched for a plug-in?

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jsdt-jquery was the last I've seen. See if you can find the version of JQuery you're using on that site.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, I'm the author of [tern.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Getting-Started)

I suggest you that you [install tern.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Installation-Update-Site) which extends JSDT Editor and provides a [jQuery support](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-&-jQuery-support)

[image: jQuery completion]

and too [jQuery completion for CSS selectors](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-&-jQuery-Extension-support)

[image: jQyery CSS selector completion]